# Can pets acquire instrinsics?

Tags: nethack

My dog just ate a mountain nymph corpse. Stupid dog. Does it have a chance of acquiring teleportitis as a result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pets cannot gain intrinsics from eating corpses.  They *can* gain levels from eating wraith corpses, to a certain extent.  They can also gain intrinsics through other methods (e.g. wand of speed).

([Source](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Forum:Can_pets_(grey_D)_gain_intrinsics_from_eating_corpses%3F))